# How do I get the name of the running batch file while in a label?

Tags: windows, batch-file

When I run

```
call :label
:label
echo %~0
pause
```

instead of echoing "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Batch.bat", it echos ":label".
I'd like it to echo "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Batch.bat" instead of echoing ":label".

I wold not like to resort to storing %~0 before calling :label.

Can it be done? If so, how can it be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not any special requirement to get it working

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    call :label
    goto :eof

:label
    echo %0
    echo %~f0
    echo %~nx0
```

This code will show

```
W:\test>labelTest.cmd
:label
W:\test\labelTest.cmd
labelTest.cmd
```

If you use any of the modifiers of the `%0` subroutine argument that make reference to the elements of the file name/path/... , they will force the usage of the batch file as data source instead of the label name.

Comment: This is perfect because I don't have to make any changes in my current code! I tested your code without the setlocal and it works.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

```
call :label "%~0"
:label
echo %~0 %~1
pause
```

But what the point is escapes me.

Comment: I'm happy with this answer because of the fact that it doesn't save a variable, and the batch file path is still accessible in %~1. However, it'd be nice if the user didn't specify "%~0", or at least a way to check that %~1 in :label is indeed the batch file and not just a totally random batch file.

Comment: `%0` (= zeroth and "hidden" argument of the batch-file) is always the path to the batch-file itself (including filename etc). With `call :label "%~0"` This is passed like a parameter to a function. In that case then, `:label` gets the zeroth hidden argument. To get you batch-files path you have to get the first actual parameter. The user has not to specify anything here!

Comment: @geisterfurz007 With the way my code is currently, the user simply adds my code to the end of their code, and they get a bunch of new functions, of which some of them require %0. Thanks to MC ND, I don't have to add any load to the user's code by making them require to set %0.